# Angular-Fullstack: Using $resourse query with params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I'm using Angular-Fullstack generator, and I'm not able to get a list of drivers depending on a companyID, through $resource query. This is what I have:

**server/api/driver/index.js:**

```
router.get('/:company', controller.index);
```

**server/api/driver/driver.controller.js:**

```
export function index(req, res) {
  return Driver.find({company: req.params.company}).exec()
    .then(function(res){
       console.log(res); /* I get here the result correctly */
       respondWithResult(res)
    })
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

**client/services/driver.service.js:**

```
export function DriverResource($resource) {
  'ngInject';

  return $resource('/api/drivers/:id/:company', {company: '@_id'});
}
```

**client/app/driver/driver.controller.js:**

```
this.driverList = Driver.query({company: Auth.getCurrentUser()._id}});
console.log(this.driverList); /* Empty array */
```

I'd be grateful if someone could help me getting the response from the server...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised that I was duplicating the 'res' variable:

**server/api/driver/driver.controller.js:**

```
export function index(req, res) {
  return Driver.find({company: req.params.company}).exec()
    .then(function(**res**){
       /* Should be the result, not the response */
       console.log(**res**);
       respondWithResult(**res**)
    })
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close.

```
Driver.query({company: 'foo'}).$promise.then(function(results) {
  console.log(results) //here
}, function(err) {
  //here is your 404 error, but you should create an http interceptor
});
```

It's async, do you don't get your results right away.
This will work of course, assuming your backend responds properly.

**EDIT: Your backend is missing some endpoints. You should be able to respond to requests to `/api/drivers/` with a list of drivers**

EDIT 2:

Angular's resource will give you access to some methods:

**Driver.get(1)** Will make a request to /api/drivers/:id and will be expecting the backend to respond with an object representing the driver with said ID. This should be used when you want to fetch only 1 record

**Driver.query({foo: 'bar', some_id: 1})** Will make a request to /api/drivers?foo=bar&some_id=1 and will be expecting the backend to respond with an array of objects, each representing a driver. This should be used when you want to fetch several records, for example in an index.

**Driver.query()** will make a request to /api/drivers and will be expecting the backend to respond with an array

**Driver.create(data)** will make a POST request to /api/drivers and will expect an object (the created driver) in the response. Used to create a new record

There are some others, this is the ones I use.

So, your backend, considering you are using this three methods, needs to handle:

```
router.get('/drivers/:id', function(req, res) {
  let id = req.params.id
})

router.get('/drivers', function(req, res) {
  //if request was /drivers?foo=bar
  let foo = req.query.foo 
})

router.post('/drivers', function(req, res) {
  let body = req.body
})
```

As I said, there are several things in play here. If you are at a lost, break the problem into pieces. Get the backend working before going to Angular.

Comment: Got this error with your solution: `Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"status":404},"status":404,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/api/drivers","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1OTZiMzMyODMwNTVjZDBmMjQ0MmNkODUiLCJyb2xlIjoiY29tcGFueSIsImlhdCI6MTUwMDY2NzU0MiwiZXhwIjoxNTAwNjg1NTQyfQ.X7X1S7CyYGABTU9-zz85DSTa5YhfXpxOy-5YcqBTzFw"}},"statusText":"Not Found"}`

Comment: Your server is responding a 404. You need to catch this errors, maybe in an http interceptor. I will edit my answer to show you how to catch it in this instance. But best is an interceptor

Comment: Well, actually I don't understand how endpoints requests are working on this Angular-Fullstack framework. I'm just driving crazy.. Could you be clearier?? Another question, since I'm getting the company from the 'current user', when I refresh the page, I lose the response even in the server side... I just need to back to home and go to the drivers view again, then I get the response!! So weird.. :/ Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you should break down your problems and tackle them one by one. First you need a backend which responds to your requests, whatever they are. Start from there

Comment: Firstly, I was getting the entire list of drivers, and I got the response perfectly. It breaks when I try to find by the companyID, so I guess it because I'm not getting the parameters properly or misunderstanding something...

Comment: I have updated my explanation. As I said, break down the problem. Deal with the backend first, test it with Postman or something and once you know that works as expected, dive into angular

Comment: Thank you for the explanation... I was duplicating the "res" variable in the index function, so the response was affected.

Comment: I am glad you fixed it. You should take a look at express-generator. It helps you organize the code to get started